# Is there a solution to keep a cookie on browser while redirect the response?

Tags: java, http, redirect, cookies, referrer

I am building a user tracking system for a web application. People could came from many urls. I want to know from which urls the came from.
I design url like this : http://www.example.com/ref/XXXXXXX.

I create a Filter to handle incoming request :

```
String cookieKey = "examplesite.cookie";
String cookieValue = referralIdentifier;
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieKey, cookieValue);
cookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365);
((HttpServletResponse) response).addCookie(cookie);

HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
resp.addCookie(cookie);
resp.sendRedirect("/");
```

When this code execute, I cannot see the cookie set in the browser.

If I change the redirect to forward, I can see the cookie.
The I see this blog post [how to track people with cookie and redirect](https://www.elie.net/blog/security/tracking-users-that-block-cookies-with-a-http-redirect) where the blogger suggest to use code to redirect.

So I changed my code and I replace `resp.sendRedirect("/");` by

```
 resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
                        resp.setHeader("Location", "http://www.example.com/");
```

Here I can see the cookie in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Is there a solution to track user after redirection ?

Comment: Have you checked if your browser's cookies settings is enabled?

Comment: Cookies settings are enabled

Comment: Not all browsers can save the cookies in case a response is redirected. Also, as you are trying to direct your response to some address within your domain, forward the response instead of redirect.

Comment: When you will forward the response, it will include all of your request and response objects, so you can use them to track the user request, no?

Comment: @Mr.777 if i forward i can send cookie to browser but my page url does not change. I have to change the url from http://www.example.com/ref/XXXXXXX to http://www.example.com/.

Comment: Forward request is used to forward the request to resources available within the server. This transfer of control is done by the container internally and browser / client is not involved. So, this won't change the URL at all.

Answer (score 6):

According to http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/cookies_api.shtml by default a cookie is visible to "requests to subpaths of the parent from which the cookie was set".

This might be your problem. To make the cookie visible on all paths, you can set the path to "/" using `cookie.setPath("/")`.